# $(this) doesn't works anymore in onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery which only works when document is ready :

```
$( ".product_imgfiles a" ).click(function(event) {
    var img_file = $( this ).children( "img" ).attr( "src" );
});
```

but, when I need to apply that event on appended elements, I need to change my code into this :

```
$(document).on("click", ".product_imgfiles a", function() {
    var img_file = $( this ).children( "img" ).attr( "src" );
});
```

and it works.. but the `img_file` variable doesn't exist. I believe that's because of `$(this)` doesn't apply anymore in my second code. how to make selection to get `src` attribute in this case?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `img` is the previous sibling of the clicked anchor

```
  $(document).on("click", ".product_imgfiles a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var img_file = $(this).prev("img").attr("src");
    alert(img_file)
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#product_imgfiles_container').on("click", ".product_imgfiles a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var img_file = $(this).prev("img").attr("src");
    alert(img_file)
  });

  $("#product_imgfiles_container").append("<div class='col-xs-4 col-md-2'><div class='thumbnail product_imgfiles'><img src='+val+'><a href=''>delete</a></div></div>");
  $("#product_imgfiles_container").append("<div class='col-xs-4 col-md-2'><div class='thumbnail product_imgfiles'><img src='+val+'><a href=''>delete</a></div></div>");
  $("#product_imgfiles_container").append("<div class='col-xs-4 col-md-2'><div class='thumbnail product_imgfiles'><img src='+val+'><a href=''>delete</a></div></div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product_imgfiles_container">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks again, bro. you save my day again. thank you very much for your kindness.